# Dart editor crashes every time the auto completion opens up

Tags: ubuntu, dart, jvm-crash, dart-editor

my dart editor crashes every time the auto completion opens up. I just updated the editor and sdk to

- Dart Editor version 0.5.1_r22072
- Dart SDK version 0.5.1.0_r22072

other specs

- ubuntu 13.04
- JRE version: 7.0_21-b02
- Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)

got an error log for java, its to long so i just give you the header

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f4798c57009, pid=5297, tid=139947622676224
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b02
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6e009]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x19
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Hope someone can help, thank you
Peter

Comment: For now if ound this comfirmed bug report  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1088325 looks like this is a openjdk bug that doenst affect dart editor in particular.

Comment: it's actually not an openJDK error at all   


I get this same error while using the Oracle Java

the error message specifically states
"The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code."

  The real issue is here "C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6e009]  soup_session_feature_detach"

Comment: Hey Dave, yes sure you're right. But i thought it has something to do with Open-JDK because the bug were confirmed as openjdk-7 bug in launchpad. Do you figured it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776).

There is a workaround:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```